# Unable to start Application with sudo when using VNC-Server

Tags: sudo, vnc

I have installed Ubuntu server 20.04 that normally runs headless (without X and DE). Here i have installed xorg, Xfce4 and TightVNC-Server and can connect to the Server from my normal Ubuntu. But i can start an Application using 'sudo'. There is the error:

> vnc error executing command as another user not authorized

When i start the VNC-Server with sudo, after login to the VNC-Server starting an Application with 'sudo' works. But i don't want to run VNC-Server with 'sudo' with auto start. How can i make 'sudo' available when VNC-Server is started in the normal way?